# Modify adapter in a background thread

Tags: android

I **know** that in normal situation, one cannot call ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in a background thread to update a listview. So I tried to work around like this:

```
class mythread extends thread {
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    ...
    public void run() {
        listAdpater.setNotifyOnChange(false);
        listAdapter.addAll(A_LARGE_ARRAY);
    }
    ...
}
```

When the thread finishes, it sends a message to a handler running in the UI thread, which would call listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to update the listview.

It seemed to work, except when I tried to debug it, the debugger complained something like "The adapter is changed, while the listview doesn't receive a notification. Make sure that you modify adpater in UI thread only."

Does the android framework monitor the modification of an adapter even I called setNotifyOnChange(false)? Is there any way to work around?

PS. In my own benchmark, by moving listAdapter.addAll(A_LARGE_ARRAY) to a background thread,  it saved me about 126ms of execution time, which means, if I modify the adapter in UI thread, it will be blocked for 126ms.

**UPDATE**
Anyone who run into this problem, please refer to this [Google I/O Lecture](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) link. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wouldn't want to do things this way, your app may inexplicably broke on some device or some version of Android while working perfectly on others.

Remember listAdpater is accessed every time the relating UI is being updated, which runs on the UI thread.
At the same time you are updating the same listAdpater in another thread. This means that:

1. If the UI is updated while you are modifying listAdapter, the UI may display incorrect items for even throw Exception (depending on the race condition and )
2. What's being updated to listAdapter in the other thread may not be updated to the main thread, if the OS sees it suitable to run that other thread on another processor, since there's no memory barrier (synchronization), there's no guarantee that these two threads will see the same thing

So the best course of action for you would be still run the changes on UI thread, but only update a fraction of A_LARGE_ARRAY to listAdapter at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination.